# symbolic reference in MACRO IN sas

Tags: macros, sas

I have been recieving an error- **symbolic reference not resolved** when i run the macro in sas using following code:
Initially I select as set of  Role Numbers using SQL into a list as:

`PROC SQL NOPRINT; SELECT ROLENO INTO:R1-:R81 FROM ROLLNOS; QUIT;`

Then a macro is used to select each individual marks and conoslidate them as :

```
options Mprint; 
%MACRO Marks; 

%DO I=1 %TO 1;
proc sql noprint;
create table Marks as select name, rollno, marks, grade from  masterdata
where rollno= "&R&I."; 
quit;

PROC APPEND DATA=Marks BASE=MarksSheet FORCE;RUN;

%END;
%MEND;
RUN;
%Marks;
```

I got an error when the sql statement is executed, Please help me resolve the issue. especially with referencing part- `"&R&I."`

Answer (score 2):

You want to resolve to R1.

&R&I. resolves to macarovariable R  (which is not available) and macrovariable I.

You need a second & before the R, because 2 & resolve to one.

If you use &&R&I, in the first step &&R resolves to &R and &I resolves to 1, so you got &R1. This will then resolve to the macrovariable R1 in second step.

Also %do I=1 %to 1 only has one iteration, is this meant to be?

```
options Mprint; 
%MACRO Marks; 

 %DO I=1 %TO 1;
proc sql noprint;
create table Marks as select name, rollno, marks, grade from  masterdata
where rollno= "&&R&I."; 
quit;

PROC APPEND DATA=Marks BASE=MarksSheet FORCE;RUN;

%END;
%MEND;
%Marks;
```

Comment: Yeah it works and there is no "." its just "&&R&I" . Thanks!

Comment: The "." should be optional. It does not really make sense here, but it should not produce an error either.